# How to create Kubernetes cluster on IBM Cloud with service ID?

Tags: api, security, kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I have created a IAM (identity and access management) [service ID](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/serviceid.html#serviceids) on IBM Cloud. Thereafter, I granted Administrator privilege for [IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html#container_index) to that service ID.

Now, how do I create a cluster using that service ID? I cannot log in to IBM Cloud with that id. What are the proper steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by following this flow:
   1. Create an [API key for that service ID](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/apikeys.html#manapikey):

```
ibmcloud iam service-api-key-create KeyName ServiceId-identifier \
-d "an optional description" --file save-Api-key2this-file
```

2. Using that API key, [obtain an IAM token for that service ID](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/apikey_iamtoken.html#iamtoken_from_apikey).

   ```
   curl -k -X POST   --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
   --header "Accept: application/json" \
   --data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey" \
   --data-urlencode "apikey=APIKEY-FROM-STEP-1"\
   https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token
   ```
3. Use the [REST API for Kubernetes service to create the cluster](https://containers.bluemix.net/swagger-api/#!/clusters/CreateCluster). Provide the token from step 2 for authorization:

   ```
   curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   --header 'Accept: application/json' \
   --header 'X-Region: eu-de' --header 'Authorization: TOKEN-FROM-STEP2' -d '{ \
     "dataCenter": "fra04", \ 
      "disableAutoUpdate": true, \ 
      "diskEncryption": true, \ 
      "enableTrusted": false, \ 
      "machineType": "u2c.2x4", \ 
      "name": "henrik-paid-fra04-serviceID", \ 
      "noSubnet": true, \ 
      "privateVlan": "2397641", \ 
      "publicVlan": "2397639", \ 
      "workerNum": 2 \ 
    }' 'https://containers.bluemix.net/v1/clusters'
   ```